# Trying get Open MPI to play nicely with Fortran on OS X

Tags: macos, fortran, openmpi

I'm trying to run a case for the software [ExoPlaSim](https://github.com/alphaparrot/ExoPlaSim) on my MacBook. While the software is built primarily for Linux, it can run on Mac according to the developer instructions. I'm running a simple default "case" script and I'm getting quite a long chain of errors. **I suspect (correct me if I'm wrong) that a major reason for these errors is that Open MPI and Fortran aren't playing nicely.** I lack the dev knowledge to troubleshoot this, hence my hope for some help. :)

I think these following errors (end of Terminal output) are perhaps the most salient, and may indicate Fortran/Open MPI problems:

```
ld: library not found for -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:48: plasim.x] Error 1
ld: library not found for -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: library not found for -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cp: plasim.x: No such file or directory
cp: ../bin/most_plasim_t21_l10_p2.x: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/[name]/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim/plasim/run/most_plasim_t21_l10_p2.x: No such file or directory
Mean Molecular Weight set to 28.9703 g/mol
rm: /Users/[name]/ExoPlaSim_Testing/mymodel_testrun/plasim_restart: No such file or directory
Command '['mpiexec -np 2 most_plasim_t21_l10_p2.x']' returned non-zero exit status 134.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[name]/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 796, in _run
    subprocess.run([self._exec+self.executable],shell=True,check=True,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mpiexec -np 2 most_plasim_t21_l10_p2.x']' returned non-zero exit status 134.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[name]/ExoPlaSim_Testing/testing_exoplasim.py", line 4, in <module>
    mymodel.run(years=10,crashifbroken=True)
  File "/Users/[name]/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 389, in run
    self._run(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/[name]/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 876, in _run
    self._crash() #Bring in the cleaners
  File "/Users/[name]/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 1383, in _crash
    raise RuntimeError("ExoPlaSim has crashed or begun producing garbage. All working files have been moved to %s_crashed/"%(os.getcwd()+"/"+self.modelname))
RuntimeError: ExoPlaSim has crashed or begun producing garbage. All working files have been moved to /Users/[name]/ExoPlaSim_Testing/mymodel_crashed/
```

I am using Big Sur 11.5 with compilers GNU Fortran/GCC 11.3.0. I used brew to install Open MPI, and the version I'm running (according to `ompi_info` command in terminal) is 4.1.4, which I believe should work with Fortran. Open-mpi.org does list some instructions for getting a new version of Open MPI to work on OS-X (see #7: [open-mpi.org](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx#not-using-osx-bundled-ompi)) though I don't quite understand the directions since it's outside my limited dev knowledge base. I don't know if this is the solution to my problem either.

The script I'm using is the base case script for ExoPlaSim (below) It's python.

```
import exoplasim as exo
mymodel = exo.Model(workdir="mymodel_testrun",modelname="mymodel",resolution="T21",layers=10,ncpus=8)
mymodel.configure()
mymodel.exportcfg()
mymodel.run(years=100,crashifbroken=True)
mymodel.finalize("mymodel_output")
```

Please note there *should* be nothing wrong with this script. It works for other users and is the script the software dev recommends using in testing. **I'm looking for configuration/install solutions of the relevant libraries on my Mac.** This isn't a problem with the software ExoPlaSim.

Comment: The three things you quote are explicitly warnings and not errors.  They are warnings about errors/weaknesses in the code you are  compiling and not related to MPI. They are also, along with line numbers, explicit in what they are warning about (you'll find many questions here if you search about them). Without seeing your code, there's not much more to say, so please make a [mre] to share.

Comment: Regarding the linker errors (about `-lm`) those indicate different tool issues, and it'll be helpful to know what OS and tool versions you are using.

Comment: @francescalus If you go to the ExoPlaSim website (link included) and scroll down you'll see the "Usage" section and the "basic example." That's what I'm running. It's six lines of code, and should work (since it works for other users). Also there must be errors of some sort because the script ends in a RunTime Error, producing garbage.

Comment: @francescalus Big Sur 11.5 // GNU Fortran/GCC 11.3.0 // Open MPI 4.1.4

Comment: @francescalus I added the last handful of lines of terminal output (above).

Comment: Please do not include the code necessary to reproduce the problem in an external link. If the code is too big, reduce it so that it fits the question.  As francescalus explained, you have several different independent warnings and errors. You could ask separate questions about them with very different minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I don't know enough to determine what warning/error is independent of another. The gist of my query is "This isn't working, here's the terminal output, what kind of problem is this and how do I fix it?"

Comment: I've edited the question. I removed several warnings from Terminal that I don't think are relevant. It seems they were tripping people up, diverting attention from the core issue.

Comment: What is `plasim.x`? Why does the output say "no such file or directory"? The script you are actually running absolutely *is* relevant. Which command is actually saying it misses the `-lm` library? If you include some error messages, you should include the code or commands that generated those messages.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear as presented this has *nothing* to do with mpi. The problems all seem to stem from the error "ld: library not found for -lm". -lm is the Unix math library. The linker (ld) can't find it. But currently you don't show us the command which invokes the linker, so it is all but impossible to answer the question. The command causing the problem *might* be mpif90, but there's not enough information here to say.

Comment: @IanBush I added the script that ExoPlaSim suggests I use to test the software is working. I don't think seeing this script will help, but it's there. My goal is to interpret the Terminal output so that I can figure out what libraries/configuration on my Mac is necessary to get ExoPlaSim up and running. Thanks!

Comment: We would really need to know more details about the code that is actually called by that script. In which step does the error happen?`mymodel.configure()` or 
`mymodel.exportcfg()` or some other step? What is *actually* done there?